# Unexpected Token on FizzBuzz Solution

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, fizzbuzz

I would like to console.log to print all the numbers from 1 to 100, with two exceptions. For numbers divisible by 3, print "Fizz" instead of the number, and for numbers divisible by 5 (and not 3), print "Buzz" instead. AND print "FizzBuzz" for all numbers divisible by 5 and 3.

```
for (let number = 1; number <= 100; number ++) {
    if (number % 3 === 0 && number % 5 === 0) {
        console.log(number + "fizzbuzz");
} else if (number % 5 === 0) {
    console.log(number + "buzz");
} else if (number % 3 === 0)
    console.log(number + "fizz");
} else  {
    console.log(number);
}
```

Console says I have an "unexpected token else" at the last else statement (the one without a condition).

[SourceCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rN78L.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the last else is outside the for loop.

this should be right:

```
for (let number = 1; number <= 100; number ++) {
    if (number % 3 === 0 && number % 5 === 0) {
        console.log(number + "fizzbuzz");
} else if (number % 5 === 0) {
    console.log(number + "buzz");
} else if (number % 3 === 0)
    console.log(number + "fizz");
    else  {
    console.log(number);
  }
}
```